# How can I resize my iframe keeping the ratio?

Tags: css, iframe, youtube

I tried resizing an iframe on my webpage but only the width becomes larger. The CSS I added is:

```
iframe {

  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;

}
```

But this only resizes the width. How can I resize also the height to maintain the propertion of the youtube video? Do I have to resize also the surrounding component? The HTML is

```
 <div class="abstract">
          <div class="abstract-inner">

              <iframe width="512" height="288" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9yH-EmnGX4?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

          </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.abstract{

    max-width: 700px;/*for example*/

}
.abstract-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /*288/512=0.5625*/
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.abstract-inner iframe{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="abstract">
<div class="abstract-inner">
    <iframe width="512" height="288" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/r9yH-EmnGX4?feature=oembed" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>

</div>
</div>
```